# On a limit concerning the exponent of a negative number

Tags: limits

A question requires you to find out the greatest value for a for which a complicated limit(with variables in both the base and its exponent) equals $\frac{1}{4}$. Now, the limit simplifies down to $(\frac{sinh-ah}{h+sinh})^{1+\sqrt{1+h}}$, where h approaches 0. By direct substitution, this is $(\frac{1-a}{2})^{2}$

The answer is 0, and not 2, as the exponential function isn't defined as having a negative base, which it would if a was 2.

Apparently the limit doesn't exist due to the surrounding values of 2, and not when the exponent is exactly 2, as the expression obviously exists at that exact point and equals $\frac{1}{4}$.

So is it due to the fact that as the limit approaches the exact value, there are multiple points where the expression becomes complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question posed in the last paragraph is, It depends on your definition of limit. It also depends on what you consider the "natural" domain of a function when the formula used to define it doesn't always make sense.

If $1-a\over2$ is negative, then $\sin h-ah\over h+\sin h$ will be negative for all values of $h$ near $0$, in which case the exponential function is rarely real (only when the exponent $1+\sqrt{1+h}$ is rational with odd denominator), so the function is undefined at most points. If your definition of limit requires the function to be defined at *all* points in a (punctured) neighborhood of the point being tended to, then that's enough to conclude the limit does not exist (in which case the answer to the question in the OP's last paragraph is simply Yes).

But if your definition of limit requires only that the function be defined *somewhere* in each (punctured) neighborhood of the point being tended to, then you have to look a bit more closely. Now the natural domain of the function $(\sin h-ah)/(h+\sin h)^{1+\sqrt{1+h}}$ (for $h$ near $0$) consists of points for which $1+\sqrt{1+h}=m/n$ with $n$ odd, so we can ask if we have a well-defined limit as $m/n\to2$.

We don't.

We don't because there are two ways to approach $2$ using fractions with odd denominator. If we approach $2$ using fractions with *even* numerator, e.g., ${m\over n}={2\cdot3^k+2\over3^k}$, then we indeed get $\left(1-a\over2\right)^2$. But if we approach $2$ using fractions with *odd* denominator, then (when $1-a\over2$ is negative) we get $-\left(1-a\over2\right)^2$. Since these values are different, the limit does not exist.

In sum, the reason the limit does not exist when $(1-a)/2$ is negative is related to the fact that the expression takes complex values at multiple points, but the precise reason is a bit more complicated, depending on how you define things.

Comment: Great answer! What did you mean by 'even even' numerators, though?

Comment: @HarryHolmes, thank you for your comment. "Even even" was a typo for "with even." Fixed now.

Comment: Also, which is the official definition of the limit? That's actually what the essence of the question is; if cases in which multiple points close to the neighborhood aren't defined are considered existing limits of not.

Comment: @HarryHolmes, can any definition really be called "official"? It's a little like asking for the "official" square root of a complex number. Sometimes you see a convention in which $\sqrt z$ always has nonnegative real part, and sometimes you seen a convention in which is has nonnegative imaginary part. The important thing is to be aware of what convention (or definition) is being used -- and not to mix them together or change horses midstream. If this problem appeared in a textbook, then the textbook should contain the relevant definitions it is using. I'd suggest looking there.