# Is the limit of a continuous function at a point is just the actual value of the function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I always though that the limit of a continuous function at a point is the actual value of that function. This formally means:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$, assuming that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Wolfram Alpha seems to agree.

[image: Wolfram_image]

This is [the link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+as+x-%3E+1+%28-1%2F2%29%5E%281%2Bsqrt%28x%29%29) of the solution for those who are curious.

This is the [Epsilon-Delta definition of a limit](https://brilliant.org/wiki/epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit/), which I'm sure you're all familiar with:

[image: Brilliant_image]

According to this, the difference between the quantity being approached and the actual quantity ($ |x - x_0|$) is always greater than 0 (not equal to 0), so in that way you can't just plug in the quantity being approached (continuous or not). This renders the original statement false.

The reason I'm curious about this is because of a controversial JEE - Advanced (Indian competitive exam) question:

The largest value of the non - negative integer $a$ for which
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1})^{\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{1}{4}$ is ______?

Some people say the answer is 0, others say it is 2. Applying the formal definition of a limit gives 0, but Wolfram Alpha says 2. So what is the correct answer?

Comment: I just read the problem and haven't thought about it too long, but I'm confused. If a is a non-negative integer then how can a function of a be continuous along a?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is continuous if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$. Some authors, however, will not define $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ if $a$ is not a limit point of $\mathrm{dom} f$, so one does need to be a bit careful when stating this. See, for example, chapter 4 of Rudin's PMA

Comment: BTW, found this resource that confirms that the limit at a point does not equal the function's value despite continuity: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-limits-new/bc-1-2/a/limits-intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{{x \to a}} f(x)$ is defined if there's a continuous path to the value at $x=a$.

Let the limit value be $y$ in this discussion

In this question, when we say that $a =2 $, we are basically saying that $\lim_{{x \to 1}} (\text{negative number})^{(1 + \sqrt{x})} =1/4 $, but when the power is tending to 2, the limit is not approaching $y$ continuously, instead erratically.

For $a = 0$, The left hand limit turns out to be $\left(\frac{0^{+}}{2^{*} 0^{-}}\right)^{2}$

For $a = 0$, The right hand limit turns out to be $\left(\frac{0^{-}}{2^{*} 0^{+}}\right)^{2}$

While, there's no such anomaly for the case of  $ a = 0$

Answer (score 0):

If you try to take logarithm on both sides you end up with $a = 0,2$, where $a = 2$ implies the quotient $\frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1}$ is negative by algebraic manipulation. I actually found [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3939726) where the concerned expression is equivalent to the one above, and [the given answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3939818/792702) explains the issue in this case.